# Session is null when [authentication mode="Forms"]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-10

I ran an ASP.NET MVC application, it worked fine in the built in ASP.NET Development Server. However, something is wrong when deploying it to IIS, Windows Server. This session is null when I access the app using ipaddress to specify the url.

To access my app using the link `http://localhost/myapp/login/` => everything works fine

But when accessing my app by link `http:/ipaddress/myapp/login/` => login successful but when redirect to next page session is null

My code: session[loginID] is null and (this.User.Identity.Name = empty) => I don't know why it is empty. Why is session[loginID] null and (this.User.Identity.Name) not equal to the value I entered in the login form?

Here is my config:

```
<sessionState timeout="120" cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" />
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="120" name="ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
</authentication>
```

I really appreciate your advice!

Thanks

[More description]

When I run on IIS (Window server)

- Use the link: `http://localhost/myapp/login/` => successful login and redirect to the next screen
- Using the link: `http:/ipaddress/myapp/login/` => login is successful but when redirecting to the next screen, the SESSION is NULL
- My code is as follows:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
         {
              //Session[Const.SESSION_LOGIN] == null --> WHY?
         }
}

public class LoginController : BaseController
{
         [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
         [HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(Exception))]
         [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
         public ActionResult Login(IndexModel model)
         {
                if(checkLogin(model)){
                      SESSION[Const.SESSION_LOGIN] = model;
                      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manager", new { UserCode = ((IndexModel)_model).User.UserCode });
                }
         }
}

public sealed class ManagerController : BaseController
{
         [SessionChecker(SessionKey = Const.SESSION_LOGIN)]
         [HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(Exception))]
         public ActionResultIndex(string UserCode)
         {
               ...
         }
}
```

I'm not sure why Session[Const.SESSION_LOGIN] == null in BaseController

Comment: Does it work when you access http://ipaddress? or do you get this issue when you use other authentication methods?

Comment: I have described the problem more, please help me find the solution

Comment: Please check whether there is SessionId in your browser. If not, please check whether cookies are enabled in the browser.